# If $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=5$, find the maximum value of both $x+y+z$ and $\left(x\right)^{2}+\left(2y\right)^{2}+\left(3z\right)^{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found out the maximum value of $\left(x+2y+3z\right)^{2}$ to be 70 using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. How do I proceed to find the maximum value of $\left(x\right)^{2}+\left(2y\right)^{2}+\left(3z\right)^{2}$?

At the same time I was also interested in finding the maximum value of $x+y+z$. Is there any way to find this, or is a separate piece of info required to answer this part?

Comment: Use the Lagrange-multipliers method. Let $f(x,y,z)$ be the function you want to maximize, and $g(x)$ be the condition, which is $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-5$ in your case. Then the maximum of $f$, given $g$, is taken on in a point where $\nabla f(x,y,z)+\lambda \nabla g(x,y,z)=0$, for all four of the $x,y,z,\lambda$ variables.

Comment: @DanielP Smoothing works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CS inequality, both can be addressed in exactly the same manner.
$$5\cdot3=(x^2+y^2+z^2)(1+1+1) \geqslant (x+y+z)^2 \implies x+y+z \leqslant \sqrt{15}$$
As equality is possible for $x=y=z=\sqrt{\frac53}$, this is the maximum.

For the second one, using CS inequality, we can say
$$5\cdot 14=(x^2+y^2+z^2)(1+4+9) \geqslant(x+2y+3z)^2 \\ \implies x+2y+3z \leqslant \sqrt{70}$$
Further when $x:y:z=1:2:3$ equality is possible here, hence this bound gives the maximum.

However if instead you wanted to find the maximum of
$x^2+4y^2+9z^2$, then the simplest way is to note that you need maximum weightage on $z$, so $(x, y, z)=(0, 0, \sqrt5)$ is the best you can do for a maximum of $45$.

Comment: I am new to the concept of CS inequality, but I understood the first part.
But how would you know that $z$ has to have maximum weightage in the expression $x^{2}+4y^{2}+9z^{2}$?
I know that $z^{2}$ is associated with coefficient 9, but can't we distribute values other than 0 among $x$, $y$ and $z$ to get a different value for a maximum?

Comment: @RoySaldanha The squares don't matter in this case, it is equivalent to saying for non-negatives $a, b, c$ s.t. $a+b+c=5$, how do I maximise $a+4b+9c$.  Any portion you add to $c$ gets a weight of $9$ in the objective function, which is unbeatable by any other variable, hence all of the $5$ will get allotted to $c$ to maximise.

Comment: If thats not convincing enough, consider $45-(x^2+4y^2+9z^2) =9(x^2+y^2+z^2)-(x^2+4y^2+9z^2) = 8x^2+5y^2 \geqslant 0$, with equality possible iff $(x^2, y^2, z^2)=(0, 0, 5)$.  Or more formally it would follow from the fact that the objective function is convex, hence achieving maxima  at one of the corners of the domain.

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Part 1:

By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, $$(1^2+1^2+1^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)=15\geq(x+y+z)^2$$
Hence, the maximum of $x+y+z$ is $\boxed{\sqrt{15}}$ with equality if and only if $x=y=z=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}$.

Part 2 is by smoothing, I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: $x+y+z\leq \sqrt{15}$ doesnt implie in general that is the maximum

Comment: @GuillermoGarcíaSáez May you explain?